# React filtering elements in state that matches array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

i am working on a project :
I list elements from json data. The user must filter the elements by their taxonomies (clicking on tags).

I created 3 states :

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]); /* Store the jobs retrieved from Json Data */
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]); /* Store the taxlist of filters */
const [filteredJobs, setFilteredJobs] = useState([]); /* Store the list of Jobs according to user filters */
```

Here is how i would achieve this :

```
    const addFilter = el =>{
        !filters.includes(el) && setFilters([...filters, el]); // add the clicked filter to the list of filters 
        setFilteredJobs(filteredJobs.filter(
            item => {
                 let arrItemTax = [item.role, item.level,...item.languages,...item.tools];
                    for(let i=0;i<filters.length;i++){
                        return arrItemTax.includes(i) && item;
                     }
                 }
         ));

    }
```

Basically i want to match my filters with the taxonomy list of each item if so display the item.
It works fine when not in a loop but i would like to make it reversable after that (meaning when deleting a filter i could filter again with the filter array updated...

[filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6nVc.png)

[job list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qncvY.png)

I don't know if i am clear, i am new to this... :)

Comment: Is your `addFilter` function working as expected? Do you need help in writing the `removeFilter` function?

Comment: It works if i do `return arrItemFilters.includes(i) && item; ` but it doesn't when i try to loop through the array of filters. I will see the removeFilter afterward, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to apply filtering for multiple filters.

In that case I would also suggest to separate that process.

The `doFilter` function filters your jobs based on your applied filters. The use of `filters.every` ensures that all filters must be applied.

```
  const addFilter = (filter) => {
    !filters.includes(filter) && setFilters((curr) => [...curr, filter]);
  };

  const doFilter = () => {
    setFilteredJobs(
      jobs.filter((item) =>
        filters.every((filter) =>
          [item.role, item.level, ...item.languages, ...item.tools].includes(
            filter
          )
        )
      )
    );
  };
```

If you want the filter to work loosely, you might change `filters.every` to `filters.some`.

**Additionally:**
Removing your filter would be relatively easy since you just have to remove that from the `filters` state and then call `doFilter` again.

Comment: Hey, this seems like the logic i wanted to implement but i was evolving step by step hehe...i try this as soon as possible thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have a single source of truth for each piece of data in your state.

Instead of trying to sync your `jobs` and `filters` state with the derived `filteredJobs` state, just use a local variable for the derived state:

```
const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]); /* Store the jobs retrieved from Json Data */
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]); /* Store the taxlist of filters */

const filteredJobs = jobs.filter((item) => ...);
```

Now you can simplify `addFilter`, which no longer needs filtering logic:

```
const addFilter = el =>{
    !filters.includes(el) && setFilters([...filters, el]); // add the clicked filter to the list of filters
}
```